# disk-to-disk backup without costly backup redundancy?

Tags: backup, online-backup

A good backup strategy involves a combination of

1) disconnected backups/snapshots that will not be affected by bugs, viruses, and/or security breaches

2) geographically distributed backups to protect against local disasters

3) testing backups to ensure that they can be restored as needed

Generally I take an onsite backup daily, and an offsite backup weekly, and do test restores periodically.  In the rare circumstance that I need to restore files, I do some from the local backup.  Should a catastrophic event destroy the servers and local backups, then the offsite weekly tape backup would be used to restore the files.

I don't need multiple offsite backups with redundancy.  I ALREADY HAVE REDUNDANCY THROUGH THE USE OF BOTH LOCAL AND REMOTE BACKUPS.  I have recovery blocks and par files with the backups, so I already have protection against a small percentage of corrupt bits.  I perform test restores to ensure the backups function properly.  Should the remote backups experience a dataloss, I can replace them with one of the local backups.  There are historical offsite backups as well, so if a dataloss was not noticed for a few weeks(such as a bug/security breach/virus), the data could be restored from an older backup.  By doing this, the only scenario that poses a risk to complete data loss would be one where both the local, remote, and servers all experienced a data loss in the same time period.  I'm willing to risk that happening since the odds of that trifecta negligibly small, and the data isn't THAT valuable to me.

So I hope I have emphasized that I don't need redundancy in my offsite backups because I have covered all the bases.  I know this exact technique is employed by numerous businesses.  Of course there are some that take multiple offsite backups, because the data is so incredibly valuable that they don't even want to risk that trifecta disaster, but in the majority of cases the trifecta disaster is an accepted risk.

***I HAD TO COVER ALL THIS BECAUSE SOME PEOPLE DON'T READ!!!  I think I have justified my backup strategy and the majority of businesses who use offsite tape backups do not have any additional redundancy beyond what is mentioned above(recovery blocks, par files, historical snapshots).***

Now I would like to eliminate the use of tapes for offsite backups, and instead use a backup service.  Most however are extremely costly for $/gb/month storage.  I don't mind paying for transfer bandwidth, but the cost of storage is way to high.  All of them advertise that they maintain backups of the data, and I imagine they use RAID as well. Obviously if you were using them to host servers this would all be necessary, but for my scenario, I am simply replacing my offsite backups with such a service.  So there is no need for RAID, and absolutely no value in another layer of backups of backups.

**My one and only question: "Are there online data-storage/backup services that do not use redundancy or offer backups(backups of my backups) as part of their packages, and thus are more reasonably priced?"**

**NOT my question: "Is this a flawed strategy?"** I don't care if you think this is a good strategy or not.  I know it pretty standard.  Very few people make an extra copy of their offsite backups.  They already have local backups that they can use to replace the remote backups if something catastrophic happens at the remote site.

**Please limit your responses to the question posed.**

Sorry if I seem a little abrasive, but I had some trolls in my last post who didn't read my requirements nor my question, and were trying to go off answering a totally different question.  I made it pretty clear, but didn't try to justify my strategy, because I didn't ask about whether my strategy was justifyable.  So I apologize if this was lengthy, as it really didn't need to be, but since there are so many trolls here who try to sidetrack questions by responding without addressing the question at hand.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for wanting to move away from tape?  Seems to me it's still the de-facto standard for your type of tiered backup.

Comment: Technically people who don't read your question aren't trolls. They're twits. Almost as annoying, but a troll is *trying* to make you mad, where a twit just has natural talent.

Comment: @MBraedley Doing tapes for offsite backups means physically moving each backup set to that offsite location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [rsync.net](http://rsync.net/) offers no-redundancy plans.  At least in terms of geographic diversity.  They may still use RAID.

(Side note: I'll bet it's hard to find any

Answer (score 1):

I found that Amazon now has a Reduced Redundancy Storage which is cheaper than the standard storage, and offers only 99.99% reliability instead of the 99.9999% of the standard priced service.

The storage is more reasonably priced, and the other thing I noticed is that data transfer into S3 is now free(up to certain amount of monthly data), so uploading backups would cost nothing, and only downloading them would have a data transfer fee such as when doing a test restore or a real restore.